# Change group vars in ansible for next group

Tags: ansible

I have an inventory like that:

```
[app]
10.10.10.10

[web]
10.10.10.11
```

And a playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Change ssh port
    .....

- hosts: web
  tasks:
    - name: Some other stuff
```

the second plays fail because in the first the ssh port changed, how can I do for pass this change to the second plays?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean ssh port for the target machines were changed ? Also do you have some common hosts in both the groups ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define custom port in your inventory:

```
[app]
10.10.10.10
[web]
10.10.10.11
[all:vars]
ansible_port=10022
```

And in your playbook run the first play with standard port hardcoded:

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    ansible_port: 22
  tasks:
    - name: Change ssh port
    .....

- hosts: web
  tasks:
    - name: Some other stuff
```

This way Ansible will connect to hosts during the first play over 22 port and over 10022 port during second play.